# Icons for "computer science" and "computational sciences" are the same

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, favicon

The icons for the two sites as both "CS" and this can be confusing for users who use both sites. It would be nice if the icons differ a little bit and are distinguishable.

(I know that the icons are temporary for beta but since betas last longer these days it might be better fix this earlier.)

Comment: Other betas have non-standard icons, too, so this should be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jin](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37/jin), our designer, has changed the favicon for Computational Science to be different that this site's.

Comment: Thank you (also thanks to @Jin :).

Comment: Now domain and logo match; time to rename the site to "Scientific Computing"!